# Intern test of async service (ftp) does not fail test on error

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, tdd, intern

I've written an intern test whose job is to make an FTP connection and carry out an operation over the connection.  If any of the steps fail, the test should fail.  I have two versions of this, one that tries to reject or resolve the async dfd manually, and another that tries to use the callback() and rejectOnError() functions to reject or resolve dfd automatically.

I have read https://github.com/jason0x43/intern-wiki/blob/master/Writing-Tests-with-Intern.md but find it too brief to really see what I'm doing wrong.

These scripts deliberately try to 'ls i_do_not_exist' in order to force an error.

Script 1 - manually reject or resolve dfd:

```
/*jshint dojo:true */
/*global console:true */
'use strict';
define([
    'intern!tdd',
    'intern/dojo/node!jsftp',
    'intern/chai!assert'
], function (test, JSFtp, assert) {

    test.suite('FTP Test', function () {
        var promise,
            creds = {
                "host": "ftp.ed.ac.uk",
                "port": 21,
                "user": "anonymous",
                "pass": "tester@somewhere.com"
            };

        test.test('Check FTP availability', function () {
            var dfd = this.async(30000);

            console.log('Making FTP connection...');
            var ftp = new JSFtp(creds);

            ftp.auth(creds.user, creds.pass, function (err, res) {
                console.log('FTP auth result: err: ', err, ' res: ', res);
                console.log('typeof err: ' + typeof err);
                console.dir(err);
                if (err) {
                    dfd.reject(err.message);
                    return;
                }

                ftp.ls('i_do_not_exist', function(err, res) {
                    console.log('Ftp result: err: ', err, ' res: ', res);
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error in ls, failing FTP test.');
                        dfd.reject.bind(dfd);
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log('ls succeeded.');

                    // Got to do a raw quit when success or fail
                    ftp.raw.quit(function(err, data) {
                        console.log('Closed ftp: err: ', err, ' data: ', data);

                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Quit failed, test failed.');
                            dfd.reject.bind(dfd);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Quit OK, test succeeded.');
                            dfd.resolve('ftp ok');
                        }
                    });
                });
                return dfd;
            });
            return dfd;
        });
    });
});
```

Output from script 1:

```
$ ../node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=intern suites=FTPTest reporters=console
Making FTP connection...
FAIL: main - FTP Test - Check FTP availability (30008ms)
Error: Timeout reached on main - FTP Test - Check FTP availability
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at new ErrorCtor (/home/neek/src/WIN/monitoring/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/errors/create.js:13:21)
    at null._onTimeout (/home/neek/src/WIN/monitoring/node_modules/intern/lib/Test.js:196:39)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
0/1 tests passed
0/1 tests passed

------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
File                                      |   % Stmts |% Branches |   % Funcs |   % Lines |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
   node_modules/intern/                   |     85.71 |        50 |       100 |     85.71 |
      chai.js                             |     85.71 |        50 |       100 |     85.71 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/               |     63.77 |     47.37 |     44.44 |     63.77 |
      Test.js                             |     63.77 |     47.37 |     44.44 |     63.77 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/interfaces/    |     76.19 |        50 |     55.56 |     76.19 |
      tdd.js                              |     76.19 |        50 |     55.56 |     76.19 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/reporters/     |     60.87 |        35 |     57.14 |     60.87 |
      console.js                          |     60.87 |        35 |     57.14 |     60.87 |
   node_modules/intern/node_modules/chai/ |     34.23 |      5.02 |     23.76 |     35.49 |
      chai.js                             |     34.23 |      5.02 |     23.76 |     35.49 |
   src/                                   |     32.26 |         0 |        50 |     32.26 |
      FTPTest.js                          |     32.26 |         0 |        50 |     32.26 |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
All files                                 |     37.91 |      8.25 |     28.69 |     39.12 |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

FTP auth result: err:  null  res:  { code: 230,
  text: '230-This service is managed by Information Services.  It holds information\n which may be useful to system managers and space is provided for\n individuals and groups upon request.  Upload facilities are also\n available.  Anyone can make use of this service. \n \n The files called ls-lR and index are a list of all the files that are\n available from this server.  ls-lR.Z is a compressed version of this\n file.\n \n Files available on the archive are to be found in the \'pub\' directory.\n \n Upload facilities for file sharing\n ----------------------------------\n \n The directory \'incoming\' is a place where files may be stored.  This\n directory is provided as a resource for communicating files between\n University of Edinburgh users and others; it is not a free Internet\n resource.  If you put files here then please send mail to the FTP server\n maintainer (ftpmaster@ed.ac.uk) explaining what should be done with\n them.  If notification is not received, the files will be removed.  This\n directory is not readable so once files are placed here you will not be\n able to see them.  You should also contact the person who you are\n passing the files to and provide them with the server name and names of\n all the files e.g.:\n \n \t\tftp://ftp.ed.ac.uk/incoming/myfile.txt\n \n To retrieve files, the exact filename and path should be used e.g.:\n \n \t\tftp://ftp.ed.ac.uk/incoming/myfile.txt\n \n The directory \'edupload\' may be used by anyone connected to the\n University network to upload files in the same manner as above. \n However, no mail notification needs to be sent to the FTP server\n maintainer and files will remain in the directory for one week.  Please\n do NOT upload files to both this and the incoming directory - choose one\n or the other. \n \n Anyone may download files from /incoming or /edupload if they know the\n name of the file that is stored there. \n \n How to upload a file to the server\n ----------------------------------\n         \n It is best to use a command line ftp program.  Windows, Mac and Linux\n systems all provide a command line ftp client.  Open a command or\n terminal window and then type:\n \n         ftp ftp.ed.ac.uk\n \n Login using the username \'anonymous\' and use your email address as password.\n \n Next change your current working directory to either the incoming\n directory or the edupload directory (be aware that edupload can only be\n accessed from the University network). \n \n         cd /incoming\n \n Next upload your file(s) using the put command:\n \n         put myfile.txt\n \n Your file will then be loaded on the ftp server.  You will not be able\n to get a file listing of it though as the directory is protected. \n \n \n FTP Server Maintainer (email: ftpmaster@ed.ac.uk)\n 24th September 2010\n \n230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply',
  isMark: false,
  isError: false }
typeof err: object
null
Ftp result: err:  { [Error: 450 i_do_not_exist: No such file or directory] code: 450 }  res:  undefined
Error in ls, failing FTP test.
<script hangs here...>
```

Script 2 - throw (or do not) from each scope to allow rejectOnError() and callback() to do the reject or resolve.

```
/*jshint dojo:true */
/*global console:true */
'use strict';
define([
    'intern!tdd',
    'intern/dojo/node!jsftp',
    'intern/chai!assert'
], function (test, JSFtp, assert) {

    test.suite('FTP Test', function () {
        var promise,
            creds = {
                "host": "ftp.ed.ac.uk",
                "port": 21,
                "user": "anonymous",
                "pass": "tester@somewhere.com"
            };

        test.test('Check FTP availability', function () {
            var dfd = this.async(30000);

            console.log('Making FTP connection...');
            var ftp = new JSFtp(creds);

            ftp.auth(creds.user, creds.pass, dfd.rejectOnError(function (err, res) {
                console.log('FTP auth result: err: ', err, ' res: ', res);
                console.log('typeof err: ' + typeof err);
                console.dir(err);
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                ftp.ls('i_do_not_exist', dfd.rejectOnError(function(err, res) {
                    console.log('Ftp result: err: ', err, ' res: ', res);
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error in ls, failing FTP test.');
                        throw err;
                    }

                    console.log('ls succeeded.');

                    // Got to do a raw quit when success or fail
                    ftp.raw.quit(dfd.callback(function(err, data) {
                        console.log('Closed ftp: err: ', err, ' data: ', data);

                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Quit failed, test failed.');
                            throw 'Quit failed';
                        } else {
                            console.log('Quit OK, test succeeded.');
                        }
                    }));
                }));
                return dfd;
            }));
            return dfd;
        });
    });
});
```

Script 2 output:

```
$ ../node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=intern suites=FTPTest2 reporters=console
Making FTP connection...
FTP auth result: err:  null  res:  { code: 230,
  text: '230-This service is managed by Information Services.  It holds information\n which may be useful to system managers and space is provided for\n individuals and groups upon request.  Upload facilities are also\n available.  Anyone can make use of this service. \n \n The files called ls-lR and index are a list of all the files that are\n available from this server.  ls-lR.Z is a compressed version of this\n file.\n \n Files available on the archive are to be found in the \'pub\' directory.\n \n Upload facilities for file sharing\n ----------------------------------\n \n The directory \'incoming\' is a place where files may be stored.  This\n directory is provided as a resource for communicating files between\n University of Edinburgh users and others; it is not a free Internet\n resource.  If you put files here then please send mail to the FTP server\n maintainer (ftpmaster@ed.ac.uk) explaining what should be done with\n them.  If notification is not received, the files will be removed.  This\n directory is not readable so once files are placed here you will not be\n able to see them.  You should also contact the person who you are\n passing the files to and provide them with the server name and names of\n all the files e.g.:\n \n \t\tftp://ftp.ed.ac.uk/incoming/myfile.txt\n \n To retrieve files, the exact filename and path should be used e.g.:\n \n \t\tftp://ftp.ed.ac.uk/incoming/myfile.txt\n \n The directory \'edupload\' may be used by anyone connected to the\n University network to upload files in the same manner as above. \n However, no mail notification needs to be sent to the FTP server\n maintainer and files will remain in the directory for one week.  Please\n do NOT upload files to both this and the incoming directory - choose one\n or the other. \n \n Anyone may download files from /incoming or /edupload if they know the\n name of the file that is stored there. \n \n How to upload a file to the server\n ----------------------------------\n         \n It is best to use a command line ftp program.  Windows, Mac and Linux\n systems all provide a command line ftp client.  Open a command or\n terminal window and then type:\n \n         ftp ftp.ed.ac.uk\n \n Login using the username \'anonymous\' and use your email address as password.\n \n Next change your current working directory to either the incoming\n directory or the edupload directory (be aware that edupload can only be\n accessed from the University network). \n \n         cd /incoming\n \n Next upload your file(s) using the put command:\n \n         put myfile.txt\n \n Your file will then be loaded on the ftp server.  You will not be able\n to get a file listing of it though as the directory is protected. \n \n \n FTP Server Maintainer (email: ftpmaster@ed.ac.uk)\n 24th September 2010\n \n230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply',
  isMark: false,
  isError: false }
typeof err: object
null
Ftp result: err:  { [Error: 450 i_do_not_exist: No such file or directory] code: 450 }  res:  undefined
Error in ls, failing FTP test.
FAIL: main - FTP Test - Check FTP availability (12732ms)
Error: 450 i_do_not_exist: No such file or directory
    at Ftp.parse (/home/neek/src/WIN/monitoring/node_modules/jsftp/lib/jsftp.js:217:11)
    at Ftp.parseResponse (/home/neek/src/WIN/monitoring/node_modules/jsftp/lib/jsftp.js:136:8)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/home/neek/src/WIN/monitoring/node_modules/jsftp/lib/jsftp.js:107:24)
    at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at ResponseParser.reemit (/home/neek/src/WIN/monitoring/node_modules/jsftp/node_modules/event-stream/node_modules/duplexer/index.js:70:25)
    at ResponseParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at ResponseParser.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at ResponseParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
0/1 tests passed
0/1 tests passed

------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
File                                      |   % Stmts |% Branches |   % Funcs |   % Lines |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
   node_modules/intern/                   |     85.71 |        50 |       100 |     85.71 |
      chai.js                             |     85.71 |        50 |       100 |     85.71 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/               |     69.57 |     47.37 |        50 |     69.57 |
      Test.js                             |     69.57 |     47.37 |        50 |     69.57 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/interfaces/    |     76.19 |        50 |     55.56 |     76.19 |
      tdd.js                              |     76.19 |        50 |     55.56 |     76.19 |
   node_modules/intern/lib/reporters/     |     60.87 |        35 |     57.14 |     60.87 |
      console.js                          |     60.87 |        35 |     57.14 |     60.87 |
   node_modules/intern/node_modules/chai/ |     34.23 |      5.02 |     23.76 |     35.49 |
      chai.js                             |     34.23 |      5.02 |     23.76 |     35.49 |
   src/                                   |     71.43 |     33.33 |     83.33 |     71.43 |
      FTPTest2.js                         |     71.43 |     33.33 |     83.33 |     71.43 |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
All files                                 |     39.36 |      8.64 |     29.92 |     40.64 |
------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
<script hangs here...>
```

Both scripts just seem to hang at the end of execution, despite logging that the test failed.

What am I doing wrong, and how else could the script be improved to use intern better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues with the code you’ve provided.

Issue one:

```
    // ...
    dfd.reject.bind(dfd);
    // ...
```

This code isn’t doing anything. It’s just creating and immediately discarding a [new bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It should be *calling* reject: `dfd.reject(err)`. Note the argument to `reject` is an Error object, not a string.

Issue two:

```
           ftp.ls('i_do_not_exist', dfd.rejectOnError(function(err, res) {
                console.log('Ftp result: err: ', err, ' res: ', res);
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error in ls, failing FTP test.');
                    throw err;
                }

                console.log('ls succeeded.');

                // Got to do a raw quit when success or fail
                ftp.raw.quit(dfd.callback(function(err, data) {
```

If it’s required to call `quit` regardless of an error condition (per the code comments), this code isn’t. An error is thrown several lines earlier. If the code does not clean up all of the sockets it creates, Node.js will never quit.

Also, the “intern-wiki” repository linked in the OP to isn’t official documentation. I’d be interested to understand how you landed there. The [correct documentation](https://theintern.github.io/intern/) is linked to from the old wiki and the home page.

Comment: Thank you Colin.  You are absolutely correct, thank you very much.  The whole 'dfd.reject.bind' situation really confuses me, the mysterious "//Ensure no HTTP errors raised.
dfd.reject.bind(dfd);" that I picked up from sample code never made sense to me.  As for the FTP socket, you're right again, calling quit even if the ls failed and then failing the test within its callback works beautifully.  That docs link was a google brainfart, I just posted the wrong link above.